# How to Late Bind Static Field to Child

Tags: php, oop

How I can Late Bind a Static Field to a inherited class.

I have tried following:

```
<?php
interface StaticInitializier {
  public static function StaticInit();
}


abstract class ParentClass implements StaticInitializier {
  protected static $_foo;

  public static function Test() {
  echo '<p>' . static::$_foo . '</p>';
  }
}


class FirstClass extends ParentClass {
  public static function StaticInit()
  {
  self::$_foo = '42';
  }
}
FirstClass::StaticInit();


class SecondClass extends ParentClass {
  public static function StaticInit()
  {
  self::$_foo = '43';
  }
}
SecondClass::StaticInit();


class ThirdClass extends ParentClass {
  public static function StaticInit()
  {
  self::$_foo = '44';
  }
}
ThirdClass::StaticInit();

FirstClass::Test();
SecondClass::Test();
ThirdClass::Test();
?>
```

Expected

> 42, 43, 44

Result

> 44, 44, 44

Problem is, that I want to have this Fields protected. I can not do an abstract static method, because of Strict Error.

Is It Posibble?

Regards.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much: This help me with my Problem. $temp = '42'; self::$_foo =& $temp; But is there a "One Line Solution?"

Comment: Here is free piece of advice: stop using global state (either directly or via static variables) in your code.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand? What you mean with Global State in this Code?